# PHP - window.onbeforeunload and auto logout conflict

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, session

I have auto logout functionality added in module which will prompt user to logged out with pop up and in case not responded by user withing some seconds,it will automatically logged out from system and redirect to login screen.

That was working fine so far.

Now,issue arise after I have added window.onbeforeunload which asked user to store unsaved changed before user leave screen.Hence,suppose user not at desk after doing some changes and in between time out occurres,it will automatically logged out from system and user won't get chance to save changes even thought there is already functionality added for this.

Any suggestion to overcome with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Simply do not perform logout action until and unless the save or discard their changes.

Comment: You _can not_ add timeout-related functionality to backend. It’s simply impossible. Please show us your code.

Comment: @ Rikesh Logout functionality is added at specific time period and it should be performed anyhow at that particular time as per requirement and also you can't stop it comparing with onbeforeunload  event as both are two separate activity where in logout is perfomed automtically from system within added time period and onbeforeunload is js event which will prompt on trying to leave the screen.

Comment: Store the unsaved changes as drafts. Present them after the user logs in again.

Comment: Please stop making trivial edits to "bump" this post. If you do this again, I will delete this entire question.

Comment: Yes Please delete this !!!

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend you to use the browser's variables. The priority of the action can be decided by you. 
You can check in the script of 
**if user not active logout** and set browser's variable. On the **onbeforeunload** event you can check for the variable.
If it is set then you don't have to prompt the user and continue the log out action. 
Else prompt the user to save his/her changes first.